# 'Watch EPERM' Error when using connect-assetmanager in Windows Azure Web Sites

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I'm using [connect-assetmanager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager) in an Express Node.js app to merge several javascript files into one. However, when deploying it in Windows Azure Web Sites, I receive the following error:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:

Error: watch EPERM
    at errnoException (fs.js:1019:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1051:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1076:11)
    ...
```

> **Note:** I enabled debugger errors as explained [here](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/04/01/debugging-node-js-errors-in-windows-azure/).

The **connect-assetmanager** current configuration is:

```
var assetManager = require('connect-assetmanager');

var assetManagerGroups = {
    'clientJs': {
          'debug':  true
        , 'stale' : false
        , 'route': /\/js\/reviews-app.js/
        , 'path': __dirname + '/static/js/'
        , 'dataType': 'javascript'
        , 'files': [
            , '/store/jquery.raty.js'
            , '/store/jquery.placeholder.js'
            , '/store/handlebars.js'
            , '/lib.helpers.js'
            , '/store/reviews.js'
        ]
    }
};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(assetManager(assetManagerGroups));
app.use(app.router);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that when changing the value of **stale** to **true**, the error disappears. The **stale** configuration makes connect-assetmanager not to look for file changes, so I assume that iisnode does not allow for this type of 'watch' operation in Azure Web Sites.